# My android app icon does not appear

Tags: android, android-intent

I declared an intent filter in order to open csv files in my Main Activity, since that the app icon 
disapeared from my device when I launch it, here is the code in my manifest file :

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/launcher_ic"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

<activity
        android:name=".Main"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter
             android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:priority="1" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:mimeType="text/csv" />
            <data android:pathPattern="*.csv" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host=" "
                android:mimeType="text/csv"
                android:pathPattern="..csv"
                android:scheme="http" />
            <data
                android:host=" "
                android:mimeType="text/csv"
                android:pathPattern="..csv"
                android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

How to avoid this ?
thanks

Comment: have you closed </application> ? and check whether it is launcher_ic or ic_launcher?

Answer (score 0):

The app's icon is declared in the application tag of the manifest, not the activity's.

Example:

```
<application
        android:name="com.example.my_app"
        android:icon="@drawable/my_app_icon"        
        android:label="@string/app_name">
```